# How to debug Rails I18N lookup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-2

In the Rails docs there seem to be different default locations for I18N strings, depending if the I18N-lookup was initiated from a view, model / validation, controller, helper, ..., if it's a label, etc...

How can I see where Rails is trying to lookup things by default, e.g. when I just use t('.something') ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can monkey patch the I18N backend in development mode to print out the I18n keys that are looked up in the backend.

Check here:

http://www.unixgods.org/Rails/where_is_Rails_trying_to_lookup_L10N_strings.html

Comment: Works for me. Using RubyMine, you can open the gem and insert those puts in the code, and run the server within RM. clean. Still, I'd prefer a `config.i18n.lookup_debug = true`

Comment: Sorry, it was a wish. It's not there AFAIK. Do you have a reference to Sven Fuchs statement?

Comment: I had a Twitter conversation with him - search "@svenfuchs  config.i18n.lookup_debug" and click on "expand"

Comment: unfortunately `config.i18n.lookup_debug` does not exist.

Comment: Link seems to be 404 now.

Comment: Can somebody share the information that was in the link?

Comment: @PereJoanMartorell you have to check for the source code of the latest L10N code and update the monkey patch accordingly...

Answer (score 3):

the standalone `I18n.t` does not prefix your translation key in any way, here are the helper methods/modules that are responsible for the rails' magic:

(click on the "source" link below the methods' description to see what's happening inside)

**ActionView:**

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TranslationHelper.html#method-i-t

[`scope_key_by_partial`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TranslationHelper/scope_key_by_partial)

**ActiveModel:**

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Translation.html#method-i-i18n_scope

**AbstractController**

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Translation.html

Answer (score 1):

The solution above does not help find what file a key is being looked up in. I did not find any elegant solution to this, below is the best method I came up with. The instructions would have to be adapted for a production box.

1. Open up a rails console `bundle exec rails c`
2. Run `I18n.load_path.join("\n")` and copy this to your clipboard. If you use pry with [some clipboard helpers](https://github.com/iloveitaly/dotfiles/blob/master/.pryrc), just run `copy`  in the console
3. Open up a new terminal window and run `pbpaste | ack 'en.yml$' | xargs ack 'key:'` This will print out a list of files containing the key I18n is trying to access

Comment: For `I18n.load_path.join("\n")`, when multiple files define the same key, based on the order of the load_paths which file definition will `I18n` end up using?

Answer (score 0):

In rails 3.2 (maybe also lower versions), a span is produced by the t - helper in views that shows you which key was searched for the translation. This isn't a solution for all cases (from controller and so on), but I think it can be the answer for a lot of people who search for this question, where the full monkey patch from above would be over the top (the monkey patch also works for me in i18n 0.7.0 and gives more detail)

```
title="translation missing: de.<path to key>"
```

Answer (score 0):

If the translation you're trying to debug is being set in the controller, there is a simple solution:

Set a variable in the controller to a tag that's doesn't exist and read the path return by the translation missing warning.

For instance in the controller

```
@test =  t('.choco_pizza')
```

In your view:

```
<%= @test %>
```

Will return:

`translation missing: fr.unexpected_namespace.controller_name.action_name.choco_pizza`